# Eclipse keeps changing layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, emulation

I'm trying to build a layout for a simple android app.

I have 3 folders named layout, layout-small and layout-large.

In each folder I have an Activity_main. But when I try and design the layout for the activity_main in the layout-large folder, and switch the view to a different phone, it automatically goes back to the activity_main in the layout folder.

One of my 3 emulators is constantly ticked when in activity_large in layout main, as is the 5.1 WVGA device.

Any ideas on how to "untick" the device and emulator???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have 3 layouts. You need only one layout and in the folders to put the resources used in the layout in that way the app will know to take the right resource depending the type of phone hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi

Comment: Well the idea was that the images would stack on top of each other vertically for the budget and typical devices,and then stack side by side on the tablets, on account of them having a bigger width, and I wanted Android to choose the horizontal layout for the tablet and the vertical layout for the two others. Android isin't an artist, however, and can't know what looks better. I'll just have to use the one layout until I know more about android.

Comment: Android isn't an artist but you are wrong. Android knows the size of the screen and will take the best resource he has..if you have 3 sizes of the same png and you run you;re application on a xxhdpi he will take the biggest one. The only condition is to have the same name and be put in the right folder of resource. You're only problem remains the orientation. You can use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" :)